# Dehydrating ginger bug

Tags: ale, ginger-beer, wild-yeast

I was wondering whether it would be possible to dehydrate a ginger bug or the yeast part of it. The end goal is to be able to store it in powder form for longer periods of time. I am aware it can be kept in the refrigerator but it would still require feeding. I've bought ginger bug commercially in powder form so I'm sure it can be done.

Also, last but not least, is the sediment which forms at the bottom of the jar the actual active yeast? I've seen a number of posts here on drying beer yeast and it seems that the yeast is picked up from the top of the liquid. On the other hand, bubbles are rising from the bottom to the top so I'd expect the organisms which produce them to be at the bottom.

I'd appreciate if someone could shed a little light on the matter :) As a last note, the ginger bug was started with fresh ginger, water and sugar, no other types of yeast have been added.